# Slow edit when using subdivision modifier

Tags: 3d-view

When i create a Suzanne monkey in a new file
i put subdiv modifier at 3 and try to grab a vertex, it's slow a bit.

But when subdivided by 4 in the modifier it's very slow. The viewport is slow in rotation and moving even slower in 5 the subdivision modifirer.

My machine can't work with more than 30 thousands verts without slowing down
All of that just in edit mode, completely unusable.

I tried windows 10 and 8.1 with different drivers and tried blender 2.8 and 2.79 all has the same problem.

Comment: Dude, breathe! Try to use punctuation.marks and make use of paragraphs when asking questions.

Comment: *"my machine can't work with more than 30 thousands verts without slowing down"* that is not correct given the written above (if I understood it correctly of course). If you add 5 levels of subdivision you're dealing with half of million polygons or 1mln tris which is computed each time you move something in Edit mode. That's resources-hungry task though it should run quickly with more or less decent cpu

Comment: Your machine slowing down is completely normal, since that isn't a very new processor, and when it has to deal with a subdivision modifier with a value of 5, it would be surprising if it didn't slow down. I have a much beefier CPU, and my computer still slows down with that many subdivisions.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, i am not native

Comment: I was making a model of big gun but when i subdivided it to 2 it had a 30 thousands verts and it was slow, i am not over using of subdiv modifier....... And it that true i think it should not slow down at that while a much weaker laptop of my friends don't slow with the same file of the gun With subdiv 3

Comment: You could also use the viewport to just preview the model without moving and then make it 2 again, that works quite well. I do it with a Pentium N4200 and 4GB Ram, and a built-in Intel Graphics 505 without good cooling and it works well. I do have lower poly models tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need 5 subdivision levels while you are editing an object?

With each level, your geometry is getting subdivided, creating more vertices: out of every quad at least 4 virtual quads will be created per level of subdivision. A single quad, subdivided to level 5, will result in 1089 vertices, 2112 edges and 1024 faces.

Blender will of course be slow when you have that many vertices, but you shouldn't need that big of a subdivision surface. First of all, if the object has `Shade Smooth` on, you probably won't even see a difference between 4 and 5 subdivision levels.

Also, you will notice that there is both a `View` and a `Render` number of subdivisions:
[image: 2 levels]

So, as in the image above, I have only 2 subdivision levels while I am working one the model, so it is fast, but when I render the image with my model, it changes to be 5 subdivision levels so it looks good but isn't slow while I am working.

So, the solution is that you don't need to make your machine faster, you can just use less subdivision levels while working.

Comment: I was making a model of big gun but when i subdivided it to 2 it had a 30 thousands verts and it was slow, i am not over using of subdiv modifier....... And it that true i think it should not slow down at that while a much weaker laptop of my friends don't slow with the same file of the gun With subdiv 3